# How can I extract a string from a C++ header file into an NSIS variable?

Tags: nsis

I have an application whose version number is specified in a C/C++ header file, `version.h`:

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

#define APPLICATION_VERSION "1.2.3"

#endif
```

The version number is also specified in the NSIS script,

```
!ifndef VERSION
!define VERSION "1.2.3"
!endif
```

so that this string can be included in the name of the installer. Is there any way for the NSIS script to read this value directly out of `version.h` so that I only need to specify the version number in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!searchparse`, `!searchreplace` and `!define /math` to read/manipulate version numbers at compile time:

```
!searchparse /file "c:\some\path\version.h" `#define APPLICATION_VERSION "` VERSION `"`
```

This next example uses a temporary file so it can be tested without external dependencies:

```
!tempfile testhdr
!appendfile "${testhdr}" "#ifndef VERSION_H$\n"
!appendfile "${testhdr}" "#define VERSION_H$\n"
!appendfile "${testhdr}" '#define APPLICATION_VERSION "1.2.3"$\n'
!appendfile "${testhdr}" "#endif$\n"

!searchparse /file "${testhdr}" `#define APPLICATION_VERSION "` VER_MAJOR `.` VER_MINOR `.` VER_BUILD `"`
!searchparse /file "${testhdr}" `#define APPLICATION_VERSION "` VER_STRING `"`

!delfile "${testhdr}" ; Cleanup

!warning "${VER_MAJOR}, ${VER_MINOR}, ${VER_BUILD}"
!error "${VER_STRING}"
```

It is also possible to write a header with a define that is both valid C and NSIS code:

```
#define /*
!define /**/ \
FOO "Bar"
```

Comment: This code seems to create a temporary file… can you provide an example that reads the text out of an existing file, as in my question?

Comment: It was just to make the example work on any machine without external files, just replace `!searchparse /file "${testhdr}"` with `!searchparse /file "c:\foo\bar\version.h"` and delete all the code related to testhdr...